# Using SqlTableDependency to stamp Identity.User for table logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, blazor-server-side

I have a class that detects a SQL record change and alerts all users via Server Side Blazor using SqlTableDependency. I'm having difficulty capturing the user who actually makes the record change via the UI. I can successfully log the 'change' using Dapper, but I need to update the change record with the actual user who committed the change.

I have tried assigning a string variable to the actual HttpContext.User.Identity.Name when the class is instantiated but this doesn't work correctly. It will log the wrong user for some reason. If there are multiple users connected to the site, it will only log the first user who committed the change. I imagine this is because the nature of Blazor?

I have tried to access the IHttpContext via the 'Change' event: 'TableDependency_Changed'. But HttpContext is null, because it's not thread safe.

Here is the implementation:

```
 public interface ITableChangeBroadcastService
{
    public event TestDataChangeDelegate OnOriginChanged;
    Task <IList<Origin>> GetCurrentValues();
}
public delegate void TestDataChangeDelegate(object sender, TestDataChangeEventArgs args);

public class TestDataChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Origin NewValue { get; }
    public Origin OldValue { get; }

    public TestDataChangeEventArgs(Origin newValue, Origin oldValue)
    {
        this.NewValue = newValue;
        this.OldValue = oldValue;
    }
}

public class TestData : ITableChangeBroadcastService, IDisposable
{
    private const string TableName = "Origin";
    private SqlTableDependency<Origin> _notifier;
    private ConnectionString _connectionString;
    public event TestDataChangeDelegate OnOriginChanged;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private int lastLoggedId;
    private string adUserName;
    public TestData(ConnectionString connectionString, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _notifier = new SqlTableDependency<Origin>(_connectionString.Value, TableName, includeOldValues:true);
        _notifier.OnChanged += this.TableDependency_Changed;
        _notifier.Start();
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        adUserName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetShortADName();
    }
    private async void TableDependency_Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Origin> e)
    {
        if (this.OnOriginChanged != null)
        {
            this.OnOriginChanged(this, new TestDataChangeEventArgs(e.Entity, e.EntityOldValues));
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
            {
                lastLoggedId = await conn.LogChangeAsync(e.Entity, e.EntityOldValues, adUserName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                
            }
        }
    }
    //private async void UpdateWithUserName(int id, string adUserName)
    //{
    //    var sql = "update oms.OMSAudit set adusername=@param1 where ALID =@param2";
    //    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
    //    {
    //        var results = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, new {param1=adUserName, param2=id}).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //    }
    //}
    public async Task <IList<Origin>> GetCurrentValues()
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT  [ORIGID]
                      ,[OriginCode]
                      ,[OriginDesc]
                      ,[Inactive]
                      ,[StateCode]
                      ,[CountryCode]
                  FROM  [dbo].[Origin]";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
        {
            var results = await conn.QueryAsync<Origin>(sql).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return results.ToList();
        }
    }
 
    public async Task UpdateDataAsync(Origin origin, string adUserName)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
        {
            await conn.UpdateAsync(origin);
           // UpdateWithUserName(lastLoggedId, adUserName);
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _notifier.Stop();
        _notifier.Dispose();
    }
```

Blazor code:

```
@code {
IList<Origin> GridData { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await LoadData();
}

protected async Task LoadData()
{
    this.TestDataService.OnOriginChanged += this.OriginChanged;
    GridData = await TestDataService.GetCurrentValues();
}

private async void OriginChanged(object sender, TestDataChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var recordToupdate = this.GridData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrigId == args.NewValue.OrigId);

    if (recordToupdate == null)
    {
        this.GridData.Add(args.NewValue);
    }
    else
    {
        recordToupdate.OriginCode = args.NewValue.OriginCode;
        recordToupdate.OriginDesc = args.NewValue.OriginDesc;
        recordToupdate.CountryCode = args.NewValue.CountryCode;
    }

    await InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        base.StateHasChanged();
    });
    await LoadData();
}

protected async Task UpdateItem(GridCommandEventArgs args)
{
    var argsItem = args.Item as Origin;
    var adUserName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetShortADName();
    await _service.UpdateDataAsync(argsItem, adUserName);
    await LoadData();
}
public void Dispose()
{
    this.TestDataService.OnOriginChanged -= this.OriginChanged;
}
}
```

Is it possible pass additional parameters to the: TableDependency_Changed method?

I have been banging my head against the wall for about three days trying to get this to work. I must admit, I come from a stateless MVC web background. So events and delegates are new territory for me. I'm eager to learn the ins and outs of them, but this problem has stumped me completely.

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

SqlTableDependency Github: https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web API and Auth tokens in your backend, why don't you use User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value in your controller to capture the user who is making the change and save that into the database somewhere.

Comment: I'm using Server Side Blazor, so that is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30890474)